# PowerShell Select Excel Cell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have an Excel sheet which is the product of multiple CSVs.  After all the pasting is completed and the file opens, I just want cell C5 to be selected.

Previously in this script, my last step before closing all documents was `$Worksheet2.Range("C5").select()`.  It was working until I added a third CSV from which this Excel sheet ($Worksheet2) is pulling data.  Now I get `Unable to get the Select property of the Range class` and it leaves the last copy/paste area highlighted.  Help is appreciated.

## Code Snippet

```
#Copy the data from the export to Worklog Template file
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false
$WorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($SAMTemp2)
$WorkBook2 = $excel.Workbooks.open($Template)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item("Export2")
$Worksheet.activate()
#Open the Planned SO Flags CSV
$WorkBook3 = $excel.Workbooks.open($SAMTemp3)
$Worksheet3 = $Workbook3.WorkSheets.item("Export3")
$Worksheet3.activate()
#SO Range Copy
$rangeAc = $WorkSheet.Range(“B2:B26”)
$rangeAc.Copy() | out-null
#Select sheet 2
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook2.Worksheets.item(“Worklog”)
$worksheet2.activate()
#SO Range Paste
$rangeAp = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K30”)
$rangeAp.PasteSpecial(-4163)

#Target Range Copy
$rangeC1c = $WorkSheet.Range(“F2:F26”)
$rangeC1c.Copy() | out-null
#Target Range Paste
$rangeC1p = $Worksheet2.Range(“AC6:AC30”)
$rangeC1p.PasteSpecial(-4163)
#SODetails Range Copy
$rangeC2c = $WorkSheet.Range(“D2:D26”)
$rangeC2c.Copy() | out-null
#SODetails Range Paste
$rangeC2p = $Worksheet2.Range(“AB6:AB30”)
$rangeC2p.PasteSpecial(-4163)
#RowDetails Range Copy
$rangeC2c = $WorkSheet.Range(“E2:E26”)
$rangeC2c.Copy() | out-null
#RowDetails Range Paste
$rangeC2p = $Worksheet2.Range(“AD6:AD30”)
$rangeC2p.PasteSpecial(-4163)

#Trim Status down to "O" or "C" and paste...
#Status Range Copy
$rangeFc = $WorkSheet.Range(“C2:C26”)
$rangeFc.Copy() | out-null
#Status Range Paste
$rangeFp = $Worksheet2.Range(“AA6:AA30”)
$rangeFp.PasteSpecial(-4163)

#Comments are just RowDetails again.
#RowDetails Range Copy
$rangeEc = $WorkSheet.Range(“E2:E26”)
$rangeEc.Copy() | out-null
#RowDetails Range Paste
$rangeEp = $Worksheet2.Range(“P6:P30”)
$rangeEp.PasteSpecial(-4163)

$Worksheet2.Range("C6") = $TechName
$Worksheet2.Range("C3:C4") = $VisitDate

#Adds all planned SOs to the Planned SO section
#Planned SO Range Copy
$rangeGc = $WorkSheet3.Range(“B2:B16”)
$rangeGc.Copy() | out-null
#Planned SO Range Paste to the Planned SO section
$rangeGp = $Worksheet2.Range(“F6:F20”)
$rangeGp.PasteSpecial(-4163)

#Hours Range Copy
$rangeHc = $WorkSheet.Range(“I2:I16”)
$rangeHc.Copy() | out-null
#Hours Range Paste
$rangeHp = $Worksheet2.Range(“L6:L20”)
$rangeHp.PasteSpecial(-4163)

#PlannedHours Range Copy
$rangeHc = $WorkSheet3.Range(“I2:I16”)
$rangeHc.Copy() | out-null
#PlannedHours Range Paste
$rangeHp = $Worksheet2.Range(“G6:G20”)
$rangeHp.PasteSpecial(-4163)

$Worksheet2.Item("C5").select()

$workbook2.SaveAs($WorkLogSave)
$workbook.close($true)
$WorkBook3.close($true)
```

Comment: Can you add your code (with sensitive info removed) so we can help debug?

Comment: Try `$Worksheet2.Item("C5").Select()`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'item'.`  Tried `$worksheet2.item.cells("C5").Select()` previously too.

Comment: Ah, right, you need a range first. `$Worksheet2.Cells.Item(5,3).Select()` should work. Sorry about that. Check the [Range.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.item.aspx) page for syntax.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Nope, still no luck.  Tried Cells.Item, Range.Item and Range, but still get an error.

Comment: $Worksheet2.Cells.Item("C5").Select() says `Value does not fall within the expected range.`.  At least it's a different error...

Comment: You may note that I did _not_ use `"C5"` in my last comment, and even directed you to the MSDN page that explained the syntax.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I realize that.  I used 5,3 and tried it again with "C5" after each iteration failed.

Comment: I got the same error when using `"C5"`, but was able to get `$Worksheet2.Cells.Item(5,3).Select()` to work fine in my testing. I'm going home, but I'll check back tomorrow and maybe we can open a chat dialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137781/discussion-between-themadtechnician-and-nate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never got this to work.  So I ended up doing this:

```
$rangeC5c = $WorkSheet.Range(“G2”)
$rangeC5c.Copy() | out-null
$rangeC5p = $Worksheet2.Range("C5")
$rangeC5p.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

`G2` has the same data that was in `C5` but it ends up leaving that as the selected cell when the document is opened and that's all I wanted.  Totally worth it.